# A new "Jobs" page in TSE that takes us to a 404

Tags: bug

Today, this new button appeared:

[image]

Anyway, it takes us to [a 404 page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/jobs). What's up with that? a new feature? or a bug?

Comment: came here to report that same thing!

Answer (score -1):

It was there for a short time, then it just disappeared in a blink, I blame aliens.